# csv file updation with table values using PLSQL

Tags: plsql

I have a CSV file which contains an ID and several other columns. I also have a table in oracle where the ID identifies a row. How can I best replace the values that are in the csv file with the values in the oracle table while keeping the other columns the way they were before?

This has to be done with tools available in oracle itself (i.e. PL/SQL or SQL scripts)

Comment: What version of oracle are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Export the oracle table to an xls or csv file

Open the source CSV file which you would like to modify and in the destination column use a VLOOKUP formula to scan the extracted file from oracle ( the key here is ID which is used to lookup)